# How do I fix (this kind of) shading issue?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I did boolean on a high geometry mesh. Now I am getting such shading issues. How would you fix this? I need a practical solution because here there any many vertices ( and I don't want to loose the shape )
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could cut the arch with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

Then add some edges:

[image]

Rework the topology, remove or join some vertices:

[image]

Extrude inwards:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, bevel or add some support edges, you can use the *Shrinkwrap* modifier to make some vertices stick to a cylinder shape:

[image]

[image]